# Mongodb call inside POST api doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, post, vercel

I'm in a next.js project and I'm trying to save data to db once I receive a post notification from Pubsubhubbub. Inside my api js file dealing with get/post from PSHB, I console log the item received from the notification and it works ok, it console logs all the details of the item when notified, but it doesn't seem to do the save operation to the database. I've tried both with normal mongodb call and using mongoose, i'll show below what I tried with mongoose:

```
import dbConnect from '@/utils/dbConnect'
import Newitem from '@/models/Newitem'

dbConnect(); // this is what I successfully use elsewhere in the web app

export default async (req, res) => {

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    onGetRequest(req, res);
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    onPostRequest(req, res);
  } else {
    // Reject any other methods
    return res.send("403");
  }

  function onGetRequest(req, res) {
   ...
  }

  function onPostRequest(req, res) {
          ...

          // THIS SAVE/UPDATE BELOW DOESN'T WORK
          let filter = { 'itemId': itemId };
          let update = {
            'title': body.title[0],
            'itemId': itemId,
            'publishTime': publishTime,
            'updateTime': updateTime
          }
          Newitem.updateOne(filter, update, {upsert: true}, function(err, doc) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            return;
          });

          // THIS GETS LOGGED FINE
          console.log("1", itemId, "2", body.title[0], "3", body.link[0].$.href, "4", body.author[0].name[0], "5", publishTime, "6", updateTime);

    }
}
```

also idk if it worth mentioning the project is hosted on vercel.

**EDIT:** issue seems to be on vercel only, the db call works fine in localhost

Comment: if you use $set in update what will happen?

Comment: use return for updateOne function.

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi I just tried, same

Comment: @ReşitAbdullahYavuzkol what do you mean exactly, what should I return? doc? even if it never get used outside?

Comment: i wanted to say use return before updateOnefunction , could you try this , its working on my server: let document; 
Newitem.updateOne({yourFilter: filterWord},{
  upsert: true
})
.then((doc)=>{document = doc;})
.catch(err=>{console.log(err);}); 
console.log(document);

Comment: @ReşitAbdullahYavuzkol i just tried (adding the update variable to your example) and document console logged undefined

Comment: I've tried the same code extracting the db call only, on localhost, and it works, same code on vercel doesn't work, it throws MongooseError: Operation `newitems.updateOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Comment: Could you check your itemId value is it undefine or is there this value on your database and i saw your classes keys are string so it can be problem but im not sure. I changed your codes , could you try this , in this method firstly i using updateone after i using find function i hope it will fix your problem:  Newitem.updateOne({ itemId: itemId }, {
  title: body.title[0],
  itemId: itemId,
  publishTime: publishTime,
  updateTime: updateTime
})
.then(()=>{
  Newitem.find({itemId: itemId})
  .then((doc)=>{
    console.log(doc);
  })
})

Comment: I solved by using normal mongodb query instead of mongoose, specifying $set for update, and making the onPostRequest function async (since mongodb normal query needs await)